# Kotlin overload resolution ambiguity for functional argument

Tags: kotlin, mocking, overloading, mockk, r2dbc

I'm trying to mock a function from R2DBC and cannot, because of argument ambiguity.
The function defined like this in the library (it is Java)

```
    <R> RowsFetchSpec<R> map(Function<? super Readable, R> mappingFunction);
    <R> RowsFetchSpec<R> map(BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata, R> mappingFunction);
```

the code where i'm trying to mock it:

```
    val rowMapperSlot = slot<BiFunction<Row, Any, Geoitem>>()
    val capt = rowMapperSlot.captured // type of capt is BiFunction
    coEvery { execSpec.map(capt) } returns mockk()
```

doesn't compile with error "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

*map(BiFunction<Row!, RowMetadata!, TypeVariable(R)!>)   where R = TypeVariable(R) for    fun <R : Any!> map(mappingFunction: BiFunction<Row!, RowMetadata!, R!>): RowsFetchSpec<R!> defined in org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec
map(Function<in Readable!, TypeVariable(R)!>)   where R = TypeVariable(R) for    fun <R : Any!> map(mappingFunction: Function<in Readable!, R!>): RowsFetchSpec<R!> defined in org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec*

Im trying to explicitly cast argument. This doesn't compile either:

```
    coEvery { execSpec.map(capt as BiFunction<Row, Any, Geoitem>) } returns mockk()
```

Is there a way to workaround it?

Comment: You're trying to cast a *BiFunction<Row, **RowMetadata**, R>* to a *BiFunction<Row, **Any**, R>*. You should keep *RowMetadata* type as second argument of your BiFunction.

Comment: Note that the issue arise because the Java signature requires *exactly* `RowMetadata` instead of  `? super RowMetadata` (somewhat like Kotlin `in RowMetadata`) . Why the r2dbc chose not to allow super types of RowMetadata ? I do not know. It *could* be for convenience, because (at least in Java), propagation of `? super Stuff` can sometimes be difficult for chaining calls.